# DB to DB mapping in regular intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I need to create recurring job in which I have to map two SQL Server databases which are on two different servers. I need to check the data mismatch in both the tables in regular intervals because new data keeps on adding every second.

I am thing to use anyone of the ETL tool like kettle pentaho which will actually do the data mapping. Do we have any other better option to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a ETL job approach, as long as you're using SQL Server I would recommend you use SSIS, is the Microsoft ETL tool. Of course you can use Pentaho and I think it will work very good also.

Another approach would be use linked servers and a job, writing the script as a stored procedure, but in my opinion this is not a recommended way to address the problem (SSIS or any ETL tool is so much versatile).